# Photoshop: Switch visibility between two layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, photoshop-effects, photo-editing, photoshop-scripting

For example, i got two adjustment layers (A and B). At last, i will only use one of them. While considering which one is better, i can compare them by turning A visible and B invisible, then A invisible and B visible. This is not so good because in the transition, there is a stage that BOTH layer A and B are invisible. Is there a **single** way/shortcut that i can switch their visibilities **in one go**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create two layer comps (Window > Layer Comps).

Assign a shortcut to the next  and previous comp items (Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts > Panel Menus > Layer Comps)

Then just use your assigned shortcuts to toggle between comps.

Comment: Thanks Scott!! This is the solution! Thanks for introducing me Layer Comps. For more info for others: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7870a.html